# Salesforce Field Calculation with Multiple Criteria

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-lightning

I am trying to come up with a formula that will give a calculation in the "Offset Field" based on The "Enrollment Cohort City" name.

For some reason the formula is using 100 to minus record count for all rows.

My Current Formula:
IF(Placement__c.Enrollment__c.Cohort_City__c ="Online",RowCount - 100,RowCount - 45)

In the simplest terms I need to have the offset column subtract from the record count based on multiple conditions.

New York needs a formula that will be 45 minus "record count"

Online works fine. 100 minus record count = -89

New York needs a formula that will be 46 minus "record count"

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally I'd use [CASE](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.customize_functions_a_h.htm&type=5) function but looks like it behaves funny in summary level formulas. Either returns just the default clause or complains about type mismatch.

```
RowCount - CASE(Placement__c.Enrollment__c.Cohort_City__c,
'New York', 46,
'Online', 100,
45)
```

Try to cheat by making a helper row-level formula.

Here's my standard "Opportunities with Products" report on standard data you can find in Developer Edition, Trailhead playground, scratch orgs (you know, "Burlington Textiles", "University of Arizona", "United Oil & Gas" etc). Grouped by Account billing city (so it should match your situation, opp line item -> opp -> account).

Pretend 1st row says "Online"

[[image]

First I created row level formula called "city offset"
Type = number, 0 decimal places. So that's the `CASE` I wanted

`CASE(ADDRESS1_CITY,'Austin',100,'New York',46,45)`.

When you group it SF is likely to display SUM of this field, we don't want that. Either don't display the field at all or pick AVG/MIN/MAX. I've went with MAX so my table column's header says "Largest..."

[image]

Once you're happy with the row-level formula add your final summary-level calculation. For me it was `CDF1:MAX - RowCount`, your field names may differ. Make it similar to this:

[image]

Comment: I received the following. Incorrect parameter type for function 'CASE()'. Expected Object, received Text

Comment: Here is a screenshot of the error https://docs.google.com/document/d/1a8dfCqNeOvJhjmkCNRr1eDYKZmShrhJWd9WQy5BVxE4/edit?usp=sharing